# listen to 'CTRL+N' with javascript

Tags: javascript, keydown, preventdefault, keyup

I am trying to bind the 'CTRL+N' key combination, like this:

```
var ctrlPressed = false;
    var nCode = 78;
    var ctrlCode = 224;
    var cmdCode = 17;
    document.addEventListener ("keydown", function(e){
        if( e.keyCode == ctrlCode || e.keyCode == cmdCode){
            ctrlPressed = true;
        }else{
            ctrlPressed = false;
        }
        console.log(e.keyCode);
    });
    document.addEventListener ("keyup", function(e){
        if(ctrlPressed && e.keyCode == nCode){
             e.preventDefault();
            nou_element(parent);
            return;
        }
    });
```

Please note: jQuery isn't avaliable

The thing is that the e.preventDefault() doesn't seem to override the create window functionality built into the bowser

how can I bypass?

Comment: You can't override the browser behavior....

Comment: @JanDvorak but thats what `.preventDefault()` is for, isn't it?

Comment: not in this case. You can only `preventDefault` what the browser does to _your_ page. The effect of CTRL+N isn't yours.

Comment: So what if a teacher asks you to Do that? is this a trick question?

Comment: can also depend on the browser as to what is allowed as far as system shortcut keys

Comment: Perhaps you are supposed to do that for some other browser, that lets you to? Say, the teacher is using IE8?

Comment: Also, your ctrlPressed is going to be set incorrectly. As written, whenever you push down a key that isn't control, ctrlPressed is set to false. Thus, to activate your code, the user would have to press N, press ctrl, then let go of N. Fix this by moving the N press into keydown, and moving the ctrlPressed = false into keyup.

Comment: @JanDvorak it seems that it was posible after all ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You code has some problems:

- Not all browsers allow you to prevent default keyboard actions (like Chromium 30)
- To prevent them on the others (like Firefox or IE8), you must prevent `keydown` event instead of `keyup` one, because then it's too late.
- To check if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is pressed, use `e.ctrlKey`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/duJS7/) (for Firefox)

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
    if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == /*key code*/) {
        e.preventDefault();
        /* Do whatever */
    }
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/duJS7/5/) (for Firefox & IE8)

```
document.onkeydown =  function(e){
    e = e || window.event;
    if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == nCode) {
        e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;
        /* Do whatever */
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: Chromium 30 uh.. well, too bad ;)

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet Well, probably on other (maybe all) versions of Chromium and Chrome it doesn't work either... But I only have Chromium 30 to test.