# Control+N Key event in Textbox using Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a text box in my asp.net web application.i want to fire  control+N key event from textbox using javscript.I am getting all other key events except control key.Can anyone help me please??
Here is my code

```
function EnterEvent(e) {
    alert(e.keyCode);
    if (e.ctrlKey) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('aaa');
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        __doPostBack('<%=BtnHidden.UniqueID%>', "");
    }
}
```

and text box

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="Custom-Text" Width="269" ID="txtPrdCode" onFocus="Focus();" onkeypress="return EnterEvent(event)"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Use `onkeydown` or `onkeyup` instead of `onkeypress`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [listen to 'CTRL+N' with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20444085/listen-to-ctrln-with-javascript)

Comment: As noted, unfortantly most later editions of the mainstream browsers have ctrl-N as meaning to create a new tab window. So, while you can trap and intercept most keys - including ctrl keys, unfortantly ctrl-N capture is IGRNOED by your code since those browser makers don't want (or allow) some of the basic keys to be re-mapped to your use. So you have to use a different key then ctrl-N, since the browser will act upon the built in actions first and before your key event can change what such keys combinations do.